# How to load multiple pages of PHP in same division

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have three PHP pages. In first file, there are two divisions, of which, one division contains a list of hyperlinked URLs and second division loads the output of clicked hyperlinked URL. Below is the snippet for first file:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a').each(function(){ 
$(this).on("click",function(e) {
console.log(e);
e.preventDefault();
$('#sidebar').load($(this).attr('href'));
  });
 });

 </script>

<div id="content"> Sidebar <p> &nbsp; </p>
<div class="form">
 <pre>
 <a href=sample_form1.php><b>Psychotic Drug</b></a><p>
 <a href=sample_form2.php><b>Antibiotic</b></a><p>
 <a href=sample_form3.php><b>Pain killer</b></a><p>
 <a href=sample_form4.php><b>Anti viral</b></a><p>
 </pre>

</div>
```

In second file, I have form which is getting opened in first file's second division. Below is the code snippet for second file:

```
function validateForm()
{
 var x=document.forms["drugForm"]["dname"].value;
 var y=document.drugForm.drug;
//var y = new Array();

if (x==null || x=="")
{
alert("First name must be filled out");
return false;
}
else if (Boolean(x))
{
for(k=0;k<y.length;k++)
{
    if(y[k].checked)
    {
        alert(" " + y[k].value);
        return true;
    }
}
alert("Check one checkbox at least");
return false;
}

}
</script>


 <form name="drugForm" action="form1.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Drug name: <input type="text" name="dname"></pre>
<pre>

<input type="checkbox" name="drug" value="ID">DRUG-ID       <input type="checkbox" name="drug" value="Tree">Drug Tree</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="drug" value="Node">Node        <input type="checkbox" name="drug" value="patent">Patent</br></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</pre>
</form>
```

I want to load this file in the first file's second division and that is happening as desired. But whenever I am trying to submit the input, form remains unresponsive. i.e. form entry is not being accepted and onclick function is not working. Please guide me in this regard how can I load multiple PHP/HTML files in one division.

Comment: You don't have a form closing tag

Comment: I have given that Stewie.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the inline js in your form isn't evaluated by jQuery's ajax function (for which $.load is just a shortcut).

You could try moving that section no the main file, which would read:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').each(function(){ 
        $(this).on("click",function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#sidebar').load($(this).attr('href'));
    });

    $(document).on('submit','form[name=drugForm]',function() {
     var x=document.forms["drugForm"]["dname"].value;
     var y=document.drugForm.drug;
     if (x==null || x=="") {
         alert("First name must be filled out");
             return false;
         } else if (Boolean(x)) {
             for(k=0;k<y.length;k++) {
                 if(y[k].checked)     {
                     alert(" " + y[k].value);
                    return true;
             }
         } 
         alert("Check one checkbox at least");
         return false;
    });
});
 </script>
```

Still, it seems to me this is an ugly way to deal with the whole structure. There's some heavy refactoring on its way.